# How can I use convolve2d to sum the number of times both players achieve the win condition in connect 4?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy

I am creating a connect four game, the board is a 7x6 board. I want to be able to calculate the number of 4-in-a-row that each player gets. The game does not end when the first player places their first 4-in-a-row. The game will only end when the board is completely full. A possible end state for the game could be as follows:

```
 ----------------
 |2 2 1 2 2 1 1 |
 |1 2 2 2 1 2 1 |
 |2 1 2 1 2 2 1 |
 |1 1 1 1 2 2 1 |
 |2 1 1 1 1 1 1 |
 |2 1 2 2 2 2 2 |
 ----------------
```

In this case, the score for player 1 would be 10, and the score for player two would be 2. I want to be able to use convolve2d to calculate the 4-in-a-row's for both players. The 4-in-a-row's can be diagonal, horizontal, or vertical. I found this answer by Manuel Faysse:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63991845/13888307

However, this will only count a single occurrence of a 4-in-a-row. I have implemented a function to do this through brute force, but it is rather slow and cumbersome. How can I change the answer given by Manuel to do what I want?

Brute force way:

```
class MaxConnect4game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameboard = [[0 for i in range(7)] for j in range(6)]
        self.current_move = 0
        self.piece_count = 0
        self.player1Score = 0
        self.player2Score = 0
        self.gameFile = None
        self.computer_column = None
        self.depth = 1

    def countScore(self):
        self.player1Score = 0;
        self.player2Score = 0;
        # Check horizontally
        for row in self.gameboard:
            # Check player 1
            if row[0:4] == [1] * 4:
                self.player1Score += 1
            if row[1:5] == [1] * 4:
                self.player1Score += 1
            if row[2:6] == [1] * 4:
                self.player1Score += 1
            if row[3:7] == [1] * 4:
                self.player1Score += 1
            # Check player 2
            if row[0:4] == [2] * 4:
                self.player2Score += 1
            if row[1:5] == [2] * 4:
                self.player2Score += 1
            if row[2:6] == [2] * 4:
                self.player2Score += 1
            if row[3:7] == [2] * 4:
                self.player2Score += 1

        # Check vertically
        for j in range(7):
            # Check player 1
            if (self.gameboard[0][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][j] == 1 and
                    self.gameboard[2][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][j] == 1):
                self.player1Score += 1
            if (self.gameboard[1][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][j] == 1 and
                    self.gameboard[3][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][j] == 1):
                self.player1Score += 1
            if (self.gameboard[2][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][j] == 1 and
                    self.gameboard[4][j] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][j] == 1):
                self.player1Score += 1
            # Check player 2
            if (self.gameboard[0][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][j] == 2 and
                    self.gameboard[2][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][j] == 2):
                self.player2Score += 1
            if (self.gameboard[1][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][j] == 2 and
                    self.gameboard[3][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][j] == 2):
                self.player2Score += 1
            if (self.gameboard[2][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][j] == 2 and
                    self.gameboard[4][j] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][j] == 2):
                self.player2Score += 1
        # Check diagonally

        # Check player 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][0] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][1] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][0] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][1] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][4] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][0] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][1] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][4] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][5] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][5] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][6] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][5] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][6] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][6] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1

        if (self.gameboard[0][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][0] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][1] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][0] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][1] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][1] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][0] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][6] == 1 and self.gameboard[1][5] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[2][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][2] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][2] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][1] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][6] == 1 and self.gameboard[2][5] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[3][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[4][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][5] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][3] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][2] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][6] == 1 and self.gameboard[3][5] == 1 and
                self.gameboard[4][4] == 1 and self.gameboard[5][3] == 1):
            self.player1Score += 1

        # Check player 2
        if (self.gameboard[2][0] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][1] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][0] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][1] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][4] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][0] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][1] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][4] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][5] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][5] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][6] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][5] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][6] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][6] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1

        if (self.gameboard[0][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][0] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][1] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][0] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][1] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][2] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][1] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][0] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[0][6] == 2 and self.gameboard[1][5] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[2][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][2] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][3] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][2] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][1] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[1][6] == 2 and self.gameboard[2][5] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[3][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[4][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][5] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][4] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][3] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][2] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
        if (self.gameboard[2][6] == 2 and self.gameboard[3][5] == 2 and
                self.gameboard[4][4] == 2 and self.gameboard[5][3] == 2):
            self.player2Score += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you found does almost all the hard work. All you need to do is change the `if` statement to a `sum`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

horizontal_kernel = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1, 1]])
vertical_kernel = np.transpose(horizontal_kernel)
diag1_kernel = np.eye(4, dtype=np.uint8)
diag2_kernel = np.fliplr(diag1_kernel)
detection_kernels = [horizontal_kernel, vertical_kernel, diag1_kernel, diag2_kernel]

def winning_moves(board, player):
    connect_4s = 0
    for kernel in detection_kernels:
        connect_4s += np.sum(convolve2d(board == player, kernel, mode="valid") == 4)
    return connect_4s

x = '2 2 1 2 2 1 1|1 2 2 2 1 2 1|2 1 2 1 2 2 1|1 1 1 1 2 2 1|2 1 1 1 1 1 1|2 1 2 2 2 2 2'
board = np.array([[int(a) for a in y.split(' ')] for y in x.split('|')])
#[[2 2 1 2 2 1 1]
# [1 2 2 2 1 2 1]
# [2 1 2 1 2 2 1]
# [1 1 1 1 2 2 1]
# [2 1 1 1 1 1 1]
# [2 1 2 2 2 2 2]]
winning_moves(board, 1)
# 10
winning_moves(board, 2)
# 2
```

**Explanation**

There are plenty of sites that explain convolution ([e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)) but to give you some practical intuition, this hopefully helps to show how convolution extends when you have a long series of `1`'s (in this case):

```
for ncol in range(4,10):
    result = convolve(horizontal_kernel, np.ones([1,ncol]), mode = "valid")
    n_result = np.sum(result == 4)
    print(f"{ncol} columns - result: {result}")
    print(f"            total: {n_result}")

# 4 columns - result: [[4.]]
#             total: 1
# 5 columns - result: [[4. 4.]]
#             total: 2
# 6 columns - result: [[4. 4. 4.]]
#             total: 3
# 7 columns - result: [[4. 4. 4. 4.]]
#             total: 4
# 8 columns - result: [[4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]]
#             total: 5
# 9 columns - result: [[4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]]
#             total: 6
```

You can repeat this experiment for the other kernels on different 2-d arrays and you'll get similar results. Hence, for your problem all you need to do is sum all the cases where your result is equal to `4`.

**Extension**

You could, if you wanted to, come up with code that would work for arbitrary lengths pretty easily from here. For example,

```
class connect_game():
    def __init__(self, n_connect):
        horizontal_kernel = np.ones([1, n_connect], dtype = np.uint8)
        vertical_kernel = np.transpose(horizontal_kernel)
        diag1_kernel = np.eye(n_connect, dtype=np.uint8)
        diag2_kernel = np.fliplr(diag1_kernel)
        self.kernels = [horizontal_kernel, horizontal_kernel.transpose(), diag1_kernel, np.fliplr(diag1_kernel)]
        self.n = n_connect
        
    def winning_moves(self, board, player):
        connections = 0
        for kernel in self.kernels:
            connections += np.sum(convolve2d(board == player, kernel, mode="valid") == self.n)
        return connections



for n in range(2, 7):
    game = connect_game(n)
    print(f"Player 1 has {game.winning_moves(board, 1)} connections of length {n}.")

# Player 1 has 34 connections of length 2.
# Player 1 has 18 connections of length 3.
# Player 1 has 10 connections of length 4.
# Player 1 has 4 connections of length 5.
# Player 1 has 1 connections of length 6.
```